# How can I take a screenshot full

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a listbox with more 10 item, and I write a code to screenshot it on Windows Phone 8 and sharing, but it just take everything on display on screen (3 item) not full listbox. How can I take a screenshot full Lisbox? This is my code.

```
var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(lbxDays, new TranslateTransform());
var width = (int)bmp.PixelWidth;
var height = (int)bmp.PixelHeight;
bmp.Render(lbxDays, new TranslateTransform());
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, width, height, 0, 100);
    ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var lib = new MediaLibrary();
    var dateStr = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    var picture = lib.SavePicture(string.Format("screenshot"+dateStr+".jpg"), ms);
    var task = new ShareMediaTask();
    task.FilePath = picture.GetPath();
    task.Show();
}
```

Comment: So basically what you want isn't a screenshot, since you want it to contain things *not shown on the screen*, is that it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for taking snapshot of your control. Pass the UIElement to this method in which you want. Hope this will solve your issue

```
private WriteableBitmap RenderControlAsImage(UIElement element)
{
    element.UpdateLayout();
    element.Measure(new Size(element.Width, element.Height));
    element.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, element.Width, element.Height));
    return new WriteableBitmap(element, null);
}
```