# how to merge two images in windows phone and save it to isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to merge two images,one image is of 300x300 and other is 100x100, First i have created a canvas and then i created two images which i have added to the both the images to canvas and the canvas is added to the  content panel, then i created a `writeablebitmap` and render the canvas and created a method `savejpeg` which saves the image to `isolated stoarage`,but isolated storage is not showing the whole image it save a black screen.

First i created a canvas through code set its height width and background color then i created two images programmatically which i have added to the canvas and then canvas is added to the `contentpanel`

**my code is:**

```
   public void CreateImage()
    {

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.Height = 400;
        canvas.Width = 400;
        canvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        Image img1 = new Image();
        img1.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Image/Desert.jpg");
        img1.Height = 300;
        img1.Width = 300;
        img1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);

        Image img2 = new Image();
        img2.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Image/Jellyfish.jpg");
        img2.Height = 50;
        img2.Width = 50;
        img2.Margin=new Thickness(0,10,300,0);


        canvas.Children.Add(img1);
        canvas.Children.Add(img2);
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(canvas);

        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(400, 400);
        wb.Render(canvas, new MatrixTransform());
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();


        wb.SaveJpeg(ms,400,400,0,100);

        using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myPicture.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
        {
            wb.SaveJpeg(isoFileStream, 400, 400, 0, 100);
        }

    }
```

When i save the image then i am getting a black screen in isolated storage.
**How to save both images on canvas?**

Answer (score 3):

Like Stephan said, I think you are not getting the image to your source. Any way I created a sample application for you. In that you can find two partitions, you can add image to that by double tapping on the container. After that try save and check your saved image. I tested the app and every thing is working for me. Still you face any kind of issues please leave a comment.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vjbbou96w0r15r/SaveImageApp.zip

Comment: the sample that u have provided is not opening in my system,i think u have developed in vs2008 ,i have vs2010

Comment: No you are wrong. I created this sample in VS 2012 you cannot develop app for windows phone 7 in VS 2008. I am not going to build a sample in VS2010 for you. You can simply reuse the class and xaml I provided there. Only the extension method for fetching the image from library not work. All the other methods will work perfectly. Don't believe that we are here to write code for you. Please take little effort to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check weather you are getting image or not to image source. If you are getting the image; try this method to take snapshot from control and save that to Iso store.

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837148/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-full/13990649#13990649
```

Comment: @sonia : What do you mean by that?

Comment: i am using this method and passing my canvas to it bus the same error is coming that only my canvas is showing on the screen

Comment: the method that is written in the link that u have provided I have used in my code and passed the canvas to it in which i have added two images and i have taken a third image ,in the source of the third image i have passed the bitmap of the canvas,but in the third image source only canvas is showing,not two images that are overlapping

Comment: You please try to add the image to a grid and take the snap shot of grid instead of canvas. This may solve your issue.

Comment: the result is same,it only display the grid background

Comment: the sample that u have provided is not opening in my system,i think u have developed in vs2008 ,i have vs2010